# PHP Ajax error, get 404 when type first char

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I see an error in my console it says: *showHint() is not defined*, while I defined it already, also this live search doesn't return anything when I type it. It assume should work like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_ajax_php).

gethint.php file:

```
<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Diana";
$a[] = "Eva";
$a[] = "Fiona";
$a[] = "Gunda";
//Further names removed for Post

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function showHint(str) {
      if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
      } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
    <form>
       First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
    </form>
    <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You have a stray php variable `__DIR__` in your javascript.

Comment: There is a closing `span` Tag without and opening one in the index.php

Comment: @jeroen you rigth I modified it and now  I get this error

Comment: What is the real path on the web-server to your php script? Note that now you are trying to reach `http://localhost/gethint.php`.

Comment: @jeroen my url is: http://localhost/phpAmir2/index.php/product, but the path to index.php is c:\xampp\htdocs\phpAmir2\application\views\index.php. which one and how I have to deploy

Comment: You need to get your relative path right – currently you are referring to the domain root by using the leading slash, so that as @jeroen already said `http://localhost/gethint.php` is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is coming from the `__DIR__` which is not defined in your `showHint` function. Remove this or update it to the correct path in which you're storing your autocomplete dictionary and you should be good.

To echo `__DIR__` as the path to your `gethint.php` file, do the following:

`xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo __DIR__; ?>/gethint.php?q=" + str, true);`

However, i'm going to assume that you're not wanting to do `__DIR__` as your path. Ultimately it's up to you to figure out how to set the path to your `gethint.php` file. We do not know the directory structure of your application or how where you have files stored.

Comment: Do you mean replace `__DIR__` with `<?= __DIR__ ?>` ?

Comment: @Rhapx you right I changed it as you see and get new error

Comment: @Amir the only reason you're getting a 404 error is because the path to where your `gethint.php` file is incorrect.

Comment: @RhapX how can I tell to php which path to choose?

Comment: @Amir You can do as @JuanMendes said and echo the `__DIR__` or set the path manually. If you start the path with a leading `/` it's going to start at the root directory.

Comment: @RhapX to echo __DIR__ should I write  it in gethint.php?

Comment: @RhapX the error has gone, but still when I type a character there is no  suggestion as what is in demo!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69772/discussion-between-rhapx-and-amir).

Comment: @RhapX how do you start your project, I mean I am using Codeigniter it maybe there are some defaults config that blocking.

Comment: @Amir There should be nothing blocking it - you just need to set the correct path is all. All depends on your directory structure and where you have placed the file.